Tailwind responsive breakpoints only apply to some styling properties
In my React + tailwindcss app I have the following button, which for some reason is still visible well past the md breakpoint (>1200px).
function MobileDrawerTrigger({ openDrawer }: { openDrawer: () => void }) {
  return (
    <button onClick={openDrawer} className="p-2 block md:hidden">
      <CgMenuLeftAlt className="h-5 w-5 text-black" />
    </button>
  );
}

I tried to investigate why and realized that it (the breakpoint) isn't working for some styles. I've resorted to styling it like this below. However, it's not elegant and a bit of a pain to add every time I want an element to show or not based on a breakpoint.
function MobileDrawerTrigger({ openDrawer }: { openDrawer: () => void }) {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={openDrawer}
      className="opacity-100 md:opacity-0 md:h-0 md:w-0 overflow-hidden"
    >
      <CgMenuLeftAlt className="h-9 w-9 p-2 text-black" />
    </button>
  );
}

What could be causing this?
This is my tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
import flowbite from "flowbite/plugin";

export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "node_modules/flowbite-react/lib/esm/**/*.js",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["Assistant", "sans-serif"],
        poppins: ["Poppins"],
      },
      animation: {
        "bounce-small":
          "bounce-small 1s cubic-bezier(0.10, 0.1, 0.25, 1.0) infinite",
      },
      keyframes: {
        "bounce-small": {
          "0%, 100% ": {
            transform: "translateY(0)",
          },
          "50%": {
            transform: "translateY(-8%)",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [flowbite],
};

This is my index.css file:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  /* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
  .no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge, and Firefox */
  .no-scrollbar {
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
  }
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #8f8e8e;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #515151;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

* {
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(0 0 0 / 0) !important;
  user-select: none;
}


Which styles is it not working for?

@sallf sorry I should've been more clear. For the "display". So in my example using className="p-2 block md:hidden" i simply always displays and never changes to hidden. I've tries swapping them and then it is always hidden and never displays.

That should work. Open your inspector. Are the expected classes in your HTML? Are the expected class definitions showing in your styles? Is there anything overriding them?

@sallf Nope, where I've sepcifid hidden md:block, the display is 'none' on >930px. Everything else works fine, my entire UI is with tailwind, and I've been using brakpoints with display all the time. I feel like maybe something is interfering with that but can't figure out what.
